# Dynamically tax_query terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, tax-query

To display all the categories name with checkbox from custom taxonomy called `ct_category` I have the following code:

```
$terms = get_terms('ct_category');
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo '<li class='.$term->term_id.'><label > <input class="taxonomy_category" type="checkbox" name="taxonomy_category['.$term->term_id.']" value ="'.$term->term_id.'" />'.$term->name.'</label ></li>';          
}
```

I would like to display content only from checked categories. I tried following that didn't work:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'cpt',
'tax_query' => array(
            array(
               'taxonomy' => $ct_category,
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => $_POST['taxonomy_category']
                )
              )
           ); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I can guess that the issue is in `'terms' => $_POST['taxonomy_category']`. If name attribute `taxonomy_category['.$term->term_id.']` can be displayed as array in `'terms' =>`, the issue would be fixed. Spent plenty of times searching google but couldn't find any solution.

Here is the full code

```
<?php

function add_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box( 'ct_metabox', 'CT', 'meta_box_content_output', 'cpt', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_box' ); 


function meta_box_content_output ( $post ) {

    wp_nonce_field( 'save_meta_box_data', 'meta_box_nonce' );

    $taxonomy_category =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_category', true );

    function categories_checkbox(){
        $terms = get_terms('ct_category');

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li class='.$term->term_id.'><label > <input class="taxonomy_category" type="checkbox" name="taxonomy_category['.$term->term_id.']" value ="'.$term->term_id.'" />'.$term->name.'</label ></li>';          
        }
    }
<?

<ul>
    <li>
        <?php categories_checkbox() ?>
    <li>
</ul>         

<?php
}

function save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'save_meta_box_data' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }



    $taxonomy_category_value = "";

   if(isset($_POST["logo_taxonomy_category"])) {
        $taxonomy_category_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["logo_taxonomy_category"] );
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "logo_taxonomy_category", $taxonomy_category_value);

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_box_data' );
?>

<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'cpt',
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => $ct_category,
           'field' => 'term_id',
           'terms' => $taxonomy_category
            )
          )
       ); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$taxonomy_category` is already an array, then:

```
'terms' => array($taxonomy_category)
```

should just be:

```
'terms' => $taxonomy_category
```

where `$taxonomy_category` is equal to whatever was submitted from your form as `$_POST['taxonomy_category']` or `$_GET['taxonomy_category']`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Milo. $taxonomy_category isn't an array. Could you please tell me how its possible to make it an array? If I just use  'terms' => $taxonomy_category, I can see text "Array" without any value under "meta_value" in database.

Comment: where do you assign the value to `$taxonomy_category`? parts of your code are missing. when your form is submitted, `$_POST['taxonomy_category']` or `$_GET['taxonomy_category']` will already be an array and can be passed directly as `terms` argument.

Comment: I am using it in a meta box. Wrongly used $taxonomy_category, so removing it just tried using  $_POST['taxonomy_category']  as terms argument as you said, but still it doesn't work. Also nothing saved in database.

Comment: it's impossible to help you further without seeing your full code. nothing in your question or code mentions saving anything in the database.

Comment: Added full code. Sorry, I should have added at the time of posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is an advanced question that would take me time to debug. However I believe the 'id' value for 'field' is not right.  From the documentation,

> field (string) - Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are 'term_id', 'name', 'slug' or 'term_taxonomy_id'. Default value is 'term_id'.

I think you want term_id...

Try 2:

Click into your custom taxonomy called 'ct_category' and get the slug for your taxonomy. You do this in the backend probably a submenu of a custom post type.

set up your tax_query

```
$tax_args = array(
    array('taxonomy' => 'ct_category', 
    'field' => 'slug', 
    'terms' => 'term_slug', 
    'operator' => 'IN')
);
```

Set up your args

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'cpt',
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'posts_per_page'=>-1, 
    'tax_query'=>$tax_args); 

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

See if you can get that working...then work on getting it to work with term_id.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. tried term_id but didn't work. How can  I use name attribute "taxonomy_category['.$term->term_id.']" in "'terms' =>" as array? Probably this would fix the issue.